# Crashes when dereferencing a QSharedPointer to a QMultiHash

Tags: qt, qsharedpointer

I've got a QSharedPointer to a QMultiHash. When I try to get the QMultiHash from the QSharedPointer it messes up. My thinking is that the QHash part of the QMultiHash is unaccessible.

```
QSharedPointer<QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*>> aNewNodesMH(new QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*>());
aNewNodesMH->insert(1, pNode);

QVector<QSharedPointer<QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*>>> nodesMHV;
nodesMHV.append(aNewNodesMH);

QSharedPointer<QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*>> aMHp = nodesMHV.value(0);
QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*> aMH = (*aMHp);  // messes up here
QHashIterator<int, JB_Node*> i(aMH);
while (i.hasNext()){
    i.next();
    ....
```

Any way of fixing this so that it works OR is there another way of getting a Vector of QMultiHash's?

Cheers
Jeff

Comment: Is this the actual code? Or did you split it into header and cpp?

Comment: This is a summary of the actual code in cpp.

Comment: I've recreated your code exactly (using `struct JB_Node { int i; }`) and I don't get any errors. What I could suggest though is that you could try using a reference to your multihash instead of a copy. ie `... &aMH  = (*aMHp);`

Comment: @RobbieE You're right, I didn't see that - that will most certainly be the reason for OP's crashes.

Comment: My bad guys. When I summarised it to simplify the problem, I combined 2 methods into one and inadvertently cut out the problem. Turns out the problem was I was treating the QSharedPointer as a pointer and wasn't passing it by reference to the other method. Hence it was still null in the original method. Once I passed by reference it was fine. My apologies. Good lesson for including code as is. @RobbieE - what is the benefit in using &aMH instead of copy- is it only time taken or is there something else. Again my apologies.

Comment: `QMultiHash<int, JB_Node*> aMH = (*aMHp);` invokes the copy constructor of `QMultiHash`. In your example it's only a bit overhead, which can be prevented by a const reference.